# How to split and ignore a character in delimeter

Tags: php

Assume $text to be split is:

```
Question 1 - Parabolas
... /**/
Question 2 - Permutations
... /**/
Question 3 - Integration
```

How would one split to get a delimeter

"Question X -" whereby X can represent any number. Through :

```
$question = explode("Question X -", $text);
```

I absolutely must include the dash after.

Comment: post the desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use regex for this.

Example:

```
$text = "Question 1 - Parabolas";
preg_match('/Question [0-9]+ - (.*)/', $text, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Output:

```
Parabolas
```

---

If you want to do this with multiple lines you have to `preg_match_all` and then loop through matches. The question will be at index 1!